# On which SE should I ask about dyslexia?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a colleague whom I am helping to learn English and we have just discovered he has dyslexia. He really needs his degree in English and is struggling. There are simple techniques that might help him get by. Is there an SE that would deal with this subject? I don't need the advice to be necessarily professional.

EDIT: I want to add that my friend was diagnosed with ***mild dyslexia*** by a test done by a teacher. He will get the papers from professionals soon. I was hoping for a site where people share tips that can help them in daily life. Intuitively I was thinking of *breaking words in syllables or smaller words* or such exercises that can help him read better. ***I am definitely not looking to replace professional assessment.*** He just has this exam soon... I hoped that there are people who have more experience with this than me. I wonder if there is no answer because there is no such site or for another reason, maybe concern that this is too high a responsibility.

I find [sites with such exercises](https://www.lifehack.org/520657/5-easy-exercises-for-dyslexic-people), but it would be priceless to be able to speak to other persons with experience about them.

Comment: Are there any specific problems your friend has? The question might be better received as "What are some techniques to compensate/deal with X problem caused by dyslexia?" than "What are some techniques that help with dyslexia?"

Comment: @bobble I am not professionally trained, so I am not sure I pinpoint the right symptoms and know how to ask the right questions. But I've met people with dyslexia that have found ways around it. Until now I was slightly irritated with him, I thought he was just distracted and too relaxed. Now I know he simply can't concentrate for too long. The main symptom is that he reads words completely wrong in a hurry to get to the next one... I stop him, go back. Might take a few times till he gets it right. He is very bright otherwise.

Comment: He was diagnosed by a test done by a teacher. He will get the papers from professionals soon. I only gave an example. It is **I** who thought he was not focusing. In fact between the word he sees in front of his eyes and the signal his brain sends to his mouth to pronounce it, somewhere there is a disfunction... I interpreted that as lack of focus, but now I know it is not.

Comment: There are many different types of dyslexia, each with it's own burden of difficulties - ensure the specific issues are recognized first before seeking to remediate problems, else you may end up pursuing various dead-end therapeutic treatments or coping-strategies - this is vital.

Comment: @fev - Focus isn’t typically the problem for dyslexia. Please allow skilled professionals to diagnose the individual.

Comment: @fev - It will be difficult to answer your question since the individual has not been properly diagnosed.  So any user who might have a similar condition or has experience training someone with the same condition would be unable to provide an answer since their diagnosis isn’t or hasn’t been completed

Comment: Maybe folks in chat on for example [academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=dyslexia) can be of help. I assume the folks working in academia are not trained to diagnose or treat dyslexia but have probably a broad set of ways/techniques to serve students, also the ones who are different abled. It is worth a try for the short term.

Comment: @rene Will definitely try it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6):

You may be inclined to try and ask on [Medical Sciences SE](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  It seems they have a tag for [dyslexia](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dyslexia-dyslexic), however there are only two posts (both seem to have been received well).

Reading the sites [on-topic page](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it states:

> If your question is about...
>
> - disease prevention and management

By the sounds of it, you are looking for ways to *manage* dyslexia for your colleague.  This to me seems on-topic for that site.

Comment: Thank you, I will post my question there and hope for the best. It seems I have to wait for 40 minutes to post another question on Medical SE... Didn't expect that...

Comment: Personal medical advice questions are off-topic on Medical Sciences (and everywhere on the network as far as I am aware). It can be possible to ask about prevention and management of disease *generally*, but not about your or your friend's specific issue.

Answer (score 4):

Academia.SE is a reasonable place for *instructors* in handling dyslexia among their students (and there are several such questions there), and for students looking to interact with their university systems to get accommodations or to facilitate explaining their difficulty to others.

I think you could craft an on-topic question there but I think the more you focus on your role as a mentor or tutor rather than your friend as a *patient* the better chance you will have that it is received well. I hope that distinction makes sense.

See some questions to help understand what sort of things can be asked there:

[Workflow for long-distance collaboration with a dyslexic researcher?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/67503/)

[Is it reasonable to evaluate spelling/grammar in reports for students diagnosed with dyslexia?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/4978/)

Comment: I already tried there without success, but thanks to your answer, I know now why. I don't understand why they are downvoting you. I appreciate the advice.

Comment: @fev Perhaps because they think Academia.SE is not a good place for the question as you've formulated it: looking for "tips that can help in daily life"; it wasn't my intent to encourage that sort of question there but to mention what *could fit* and I appreciate that you've understood my meaning.

Comment: I understood exactly what you meant. I have deleted my question there.